# Need help picking up and moving a file with a dynamic name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to move a backup file that is created every morning from its current location to a shared network location but can not figure out how to code for dynamic dates in SQL.

Ex: The file is called `my.file03232017130.bak` and every day a new file will be saved with the same name except the `03232017130` will be changed to that days date.

I would like to utilize SSIS and SQL to set up a process that will move the file every morning from where it is saved by default to a different location.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see MMDDYYYY that part isn't a big deal really. That is pretty simple string manipulation. What part(s) do you need help with? As posted this is pretty broad.

Answer (score 0):

Make a package variable and then set the value to the string using code depending on the current date in a Script Task, then use that variable in your File System Task.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a [File Watcher](http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx) on the backup folder and utelize a [File Transfer Task](http://www.cozyroc.com/) to send each file to the destination you want. You can do it without the 3rd party tools but it will take much longer to setup and usually runs into many windows related issues